# Disable the Go button from submitting the form (Sencha Touch 2, Cordova, Android)

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a form and there is a `button` that submits it. I wish that submit would be executed only on tap on 'Register' button. But when user inputs some text in any `textfield` and presses "Go" (aka "Enter") button. The form submits and I can do nothing about it.

This behavior is noticed on **Samsung Galaxy S** (GT i9000) on Android v2.3.6. But **HTC** with Android 4 behaves as I wish.

The `submitOnAction:false` doesn't help.
`beforesubmit` too. Any of solutions in code listing don't work.

I just don't want the form to submit in any other way except pressing 'Register' button!

File **/view/userRegistration/FormPanel.js**

```
Ext.define('My.view.userRegistration.FormPanel', {
    extend: 'My.view.components.FormPanel',
    xtype : 'userRegistrationForm',

    config: {
        standardSubmit : false,
        submitOnAction : false,

        listeners: {
            beforesubmit: function(form, values, options, eOpts){
                console.log('before submit fired');
                return false; // returning false doesn't help
            },
            '> field': {
                keyup: function(fld, e){
                    //13 = user tapped 'return' button on keyboard
                    //10 = user tapped 'hide keyboard' on keyboard
                    if (e.browserEvent.keyCode == 13 || e.browserEvent.keyCode == 10) {
                        e.stopEvent();
                        fld.element.dom.blur();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        items : [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'firstName',
                required: true,
                listeners: {
                    action: function(field, e, eOpts) {
                    e.stopEvent();
                    return false;
                    },
                    keyup: function(field, e) {
                        if (e.browserEvent.keyCode == 13 || e.browserEvent.keyCode == 10) {
                            // GO pressed on "firstName"
                            e.stopEvent();
                            field.element.dom.blur();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text : 'Register',
                listeners: {
                    tap: function(button) {
                        var form = button.parent;
                        if (form.isValid()) {
                            form.onSubmit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

File **/view/components/FormPanel.js**

```
Ext.define('My.view.components.FormPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',

    onSubmit: function() {
        var fieldValues = this.getValues();
        // Sending fieldValues via AJAX
    },
    isValid: function(args) {
        // Validating values
    }
});
```

Comment: You could just disconnect the register button from the form field. Listen for taps on the button and then submit the form (I'm not sure the submit method you are using) manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the `onSubmit()` method. It is **`@private`** in **sencha-touch-all-debug.js**:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.Panel', {

    // @private
    onSubmit: function(e) {
        var me = this;
        if (e && !me.getStandardSubmit()) {
            e.stopEvent();
        } else {
            this.submit();
        }
    }

}
```

So it is absolutely incorrect to override `onSubmit()` in child classes. More correct way.

File **/view/components/FormPanel.js**

```
Ext.define('My.view.components.FormPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',

    config: {
        standardSubmit: false,

        listeners: {
            beforesubmit: function(form, values, options, eOpts) {
                // Do something with data. Send it via AJAX, for example
                return false; // returning false to prevent real form.submit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the button in the form should just call `form.submit();`.

File **/view/userRegistration/FormPanel.js**

```
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text : 'Register',
            handler: function() {
                var form = button.parent;
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to override the FormPanel for that. In the controller, you can just prevent the action from field to execute and bubble up.

```
Ext.define('TestApp.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        control: {
            'field': {
                action: 'onFieldAction'
            }
        }
    },
    onFieldAction: function(field, e) {
        // Stop event here 
        e.stopEvent();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

There is a gotcha that i encountered while doing this. I've accidentally overridden the default initialize function of my FormPanel. Every thing will not work if you do this

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'loginform',
    config: {
        ...
    }
    initialize: function(config) {
         this.callParent(arguments); // Nothing will work without this line
         ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs to disable the Enter key on keyboard or the Go button in the softkeyboard, I found the following solution:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'login',

    config: {
        ....
    },

    getElementConfig: function() {
        var config = this.callParent();
        config.children.pop();

        return config;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", onGoKeyDown, false);
function onGoKeyDown(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if(e.srcElement.localName == 'input') {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 10) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still looking for a solution, but I came up with a very simple trick - trap the input and prevent the form submission even if the user hits 'Go' or any button/key other than the one you want. To do that just place a listener in every entry field and listen for the 'blur' event. This will trap any action when leaving the field (blur). Inside the blur listener event do a focus() on the next field (like tabbing through the form, i.e. if you are in field 1 send the focus to 2 and so on) until you arrive at your desired submit or register button. Once there, you can do your processing, submit, etc. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Now, if we want to call Ajax method on submit by either clicking Submit button or by enter action then,

submitOnAction : true in the FormPanel config

Add this.callParent(arguments)in initialize method  in case we are overriding initialize method of FormPanel

Override submit method of FormPanel to add Ajax Call

Listen to tap event of Submit button to add Ajax Call